# When you visit the website or restart it, these small "confetti" pop up for 2 seconds. It's built in Elementor. Where could they come from?

Tags: wordpress, animation, wordpress-theming, elementor, wordpress-theme-astra

[image: hero section image]

It's like an animation, that suddenly appears and it's shown the new year's fireworks and I have no idea where they come from. It shows like that in another section too(in the reviews section).
Do you have any idea how to remove it?
The website is built with the Astra theme, in Elementor.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that this elementor extension pack was pre-installed? The animation looks pretty much the same.

https://www.elementpack.pro/demo/element/confetti-effects/

If so, this video might help you to understand the workflow used to add an animation and then you could simply reverse the settings: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NcKHFeeUXqg

If this doesn't work, a quick fix might be finding the animation's class and using this custom CSS:

```css
.animation-class {
display: none
}
```

You could also try "visibility: hidden" instead of "display: none".

Hope this helps!